# Beginning C and I have a bug that is killing me

Tags: c, loops, debugging, if-statement

I am writing some code and I have a prompt in the program driven by a while loop where you make a choice. However, it prints the prompt twice every time it goes through the loop and I just can't figure it out.

```
   while (choice != 'x'); 
        {
            printf("\nChoice (a)dd (v)iew e(X)it [ ]\b\b");
            scanf("%c",&choice);
            if (choice == 'a') add_record(); 
            if (choice == 'v') view_record(); 
        }
```

The printf line is the one that prints twice. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&choice);` --> `scanf(" %c",&choice);`

Comment: Please show an output.

Comment: The double print depends on the context of the while statement (which is not visible in your code), but you probably want to remove the semi-colon after the while condition.  The block following that is being unconditionally executed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What does that space added before %c do?..Is it just for formatting the appearance? New to C.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Space in the format of scanf means skipping white-space. In this case, skip the previous newline.

Comment: Here a `do ... while` loop would be the better choice.

Comment: I don't think that's your actual code. The semicolon on the `while` line means that it will either get stuck in an infinite loop on that line, or it will execute the following block only once, which is not consistent with the behavior you describe. Post *exact* copy-and-pasted code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Not necessarily. The compiler is free to assume the loop will eventually terminate, see the standard 6.8.5p6

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf: Unlikely to be relevant -- and even if it were, the block would only execute once.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I just commented on your assumption the loop is infinite, not that it is the cause for the problem.

Comment: @olaf, the loop will not terminate, unless otherwise the compiler can see that the expression uses a volatile variable, which can be assumed to change externally.

Comment: @Ravi: Please read the standard section I referenced! The compiler may assume the loop terminates and just optimise it away! It is not allowed **if** a `volatile` is involved.

Comment: @Olaf, please post the link as I see only the text "Standard 6.8.5p6" in your comment.  Also, I tried it using the C++ compiler and the loop doesn't terminate even without the volatile variable in the expression.

Comment: @ravi the question is tagged C, so I apparently refer to the C standard. Not Java, not Ruby, not C++. All different languages! "The compiler is free to assume ..." does not mean it has to.

Comment: @Olaf, all I am asking is the link to the standard document that you are referring to. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravi: is googling "c standard" really that complicated? Or just having a look at the C info-page here?

Comment: @Olaf, there is no need to be sarcastic, there are multiple standards even for 'C', so the obvious question is to see what you are referring to to understand your point of view. Hope we don't waste each other's time like this.

Comment: @Ravi: No! There is only one standard for the C language: ISO9899:2011! You would know if you have read the info-page. C99, C95, C90 or C89 are **not** the C standard!

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for sharing the details. I am going to stop here. If any one looks at this link they would know what I am referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C;   http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=29237

Comment: ANSI is a national standard. It has no international relevance (stack overflow is an international site). Also "ANSI-C" is commonly a synonym for the first version of the standard. So more correct would be ISO-C. And maybe you should get the idea of standards: there is only one valid version at a time. Older versions are commonly withdrawn once a new version is released. See the foreword.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to notice in the question posted.

1. The outer while loop behavior depends on the variables initialization at first then the values being entered subsequently.
2. It then manipulates into print the prompt to enter choice, repeatedly (not just twice) depending on how many characters entered as input before 'enter' key is pressed.
3. The char i/o driver buffers the input entered and each of the characters entered is read by scarf() one at a time in this case, from the buffer. So it is needed to rewrite the code to work as following (expected from my understanding)

   char choice = '!', ws = ' ';
   int  attempts = 0;

   while (choice != 'x')
   {
       printf("\nAttempt:%d Choice (a)dd (v)iew e(X)it [ ]\b\b", ++attempts);
       // Eat up the '\n', if one exist and Wait for valid input
       while ((scanf("%c", &choice) > 0) && (choice == '\n'));
       // Eat up all white space and other chars entered so far, except the last '\n'
       while ((scanf("%c", &ws) > 0) && (ws != '\n'));
       if (choice == 'a') add_record();
       if (choice == 'v') view_record();
   }

Comment: The code before that doesn't matter much in this case.  What is in those functions and does the  OP want to continue iterating after executing one of those functions matters?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow your response. First the while loop doesn't do anything with respect to the block following it due to ';' which means an empty while loop and if the `choice` is initialized to anything other than 'x', it will spin there for ever since there isn't any means of changing `choice` until it falls through, which it wouldn't.

Comment: Well, I was only talking about what could be the possibility after removing that `;` .If the entered char is `v` or `a` , the control is going to fall back in the loop after executing one of those functions (and other functions if called by the first one).

Comment: @jeffrey-gibson, the buffer stream input is what causing the issue.  Try the following. Setting unbuffered input didn't work as the driver underneath isn't perhaps working that way.

    `char choice, crlf;
    
    while (choice != 'x')
    {
        printf("\nChoice (a)dd (v)iew e(X)it [ ]\b\b");
        while ((choice = getc(stdin)) == '\n');
        while ((crlf = getc(stdin)) != '\n'); /* Skip all other chars entered */
        if (choice == 'a') add_record();
        if (choice == 'v') view_record();
    }`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11630552)

Comment: Sorry, please clarify your comment @happycoder.  I didn't have enough points to post comments anywhere, but to respond only with respect to my answer.  Now I have reached to that status.

Comment: Now that you can post comments, yo must delete this answer and post it as comment instead. This is because you are nowhere near answering that question!

Comment: @happycoder, I will post the comment later.  But for sure I don't get your comment at all. Did you even try to understand what my response has been? Clarify what you meant nowhere close to answering the question. Do you have a answer to that why not you suggest one. I did in fact tested the code that I suggested along with the reason.

Comment: First of all, it is an auto-generated comment. Second, I don't see using the word 'close' in my comment!

Comment: @happycoder, am I talking to a bot so far? Nowhere close to or nowhere near does sound similar to me unless I need to learn the literal meaning of 'near' vs 'close to' in this case.:-)

Comment: Well, the first comment was auto-generated. In case you haven't noticed, it even says that it was "From Review".

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a character (i.e. type 'a' and press 'Enter'), the newline character ('\n') is also being read in from stdin. You can add a leading space to the format specifier to avoid this:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

The space indicates to scanf to ignore whitespace characters (such as '\n').